# Get latitude and longitude stops in a trimble map

Tags: javascript, geometry, maps, latitude-longitude

Using trimble maps, i'm creating a route with origin and destination points given by latitude and longitude. The user can put new stops at the interactive map. The problem is that when the library returns me the stops locations, it is giving me those like X and Y and not like longitude and latitude.

For example, if the origin is

Latitude: 37.66427

Longitude: -97.72388

The application is returning me the point like

x: -10878572.558428662

y: 4532106.384744367

I'm doing this to get the stops:

```
var routeElements = routingLayer.getRouteElements("MyRoute");

var numberOfStops = routeElements.stops.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStops; i++) {
  console.log("Stop " + i);
  console.log("Lon: " + routeElements.stops[i].geometry.x);
  console.log("Lat: " + routeElements.stops[i].geometry.y);
}
```

As says at the following documentation:
https://developer.trimblemaps.com/trimble-maps/1.2/docs/routing/

I need to know the way to convert X and Y to Longitude and Latitude or get directly the LonLat with any specific command.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use the transform function to change the point back to a geographic projection.

In this case you would need to call

```
routeElements.stops[i].transform(map.getProjectionObject(),new ALKMaps.Projection("EPSG:4326"))
```

to get a Point object where the x and y are longitude and latitude values.

It's basically the reverse of what's described here: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/trimble-maps/1.2/docs/getting-started/spherical-mercator/

Comment: in trimble maps How can I get stops (lat/lng) which inside polygon?